# Parse of '@import (less)' statement raises NullReferenceException in ASP .NET MVC 5 project with dotLess

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

### **Short story**

Visual Studio 2013.3 with [Web Essentials](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361), ASP .NET MVC 5 Project with [dotLess 1.4.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/dotless). Attempt to use `@import (less)` statement inside of a simple less file, that only imports a simple css file, leads to a raise of `NullReferenceException`. `@import` without `(less)` instruction does not parsed as expected - it just being copied unparsed to the result less file. **Is there a way to fix that? Or it is just a bug of dotLess?**

---

### **Long story (with steps to reproduce)**

1. Create a new ASP .NET MVC 5 Project in Visual Studio 2013.3
2. Install the latest version of [dotless](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) via NuGet Package Manager
3. Inside `~/Content/` folder create a simple `Site.less` file, that only imports the default `Site.css` files:

_

```
@import (less) "Site.css";
```

4. According to [Bundling and Minification article of ASP .NET MVC 4 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) create `LessTransform` class as follows:

_

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
        response.ContentType = "text/css";
    }
}
```

5. In `RegisterBundles` method inside of `BundleConfig` class in `BundleConfig.cs` file add the following lines:

_

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/Content/less").Include("~/Content/Site.less");
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

6. In `_Layout.cshtml` file delete (or just comment out) the line:

_

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

and also add the following line:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/less")
```

7. Run the project

**Result**: `NullReferenceException` is thrown in `LessTransform` class on the line:

```
response.Content = Less.Parse(response.Content);
```

**Is there a way to fix that? Or it is just a bug of dotLess?**

---

### **Knowledge base**

1. Changing

_

```
@import (less) "Site.css";
```

to

```
@import (less) "./Site.css";
```

does not help.

2. Copy Always to Output Directory of `Site.css` does not help.
3. Changing `@import (less) "Site.css"` to `@import "Site.css"` does not help since dotLess does not parse the resulting line as we expect. It just copies the line without any processing.
4. [Web Essentials 2013 for Update 3](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) represents compiled version of the less file correctly. Nonetheless, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DotLess supports this type of import `@import (less) "Site.css";`  It was introduced in v.1.4 of Less but Dotless is not always up to date.

Just importing the css will work fine and then the bundling can sort out the rest.

```
@import site.css
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work also. The result of parsing "@import \"Site.css\";" is "@import \"Site.css\";", so it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [Web Essentials 2013](http://vswebessentials.com/). See if it can compile your less on save (and build).

Comment: Yes, I have Web Essentials installed and it represents compiled version of the less file correctly.

Comment: @Deilan is there a reason you can't use it and need to use dotless? We found it to be quite buggy and haven't had any issues with Web Essentials.

Comment: John, thank you for your replies. No, there is no absolute reason to use dotLess. I tried to use it because this is the only tool for processing less files in ASP .NET MVC that I've heard about a lot. I just want to import a couple of less files from some bootstrap template (written using Node.js stack) to my project. Would you kindly recommend some patterns and practices for my case?

Comment: @Deilan you should be able to just use Web Essentials to compile the LESS on save / build. Check the settings under Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials. You can have it show/hide the compiled pane (very nice) as well as choose when it will compile (save, build, or both). Depending on how you have your setup you might want to include the css it creates in your project so it gets checked into source control / deployed correctly. We end up just including the css file as they are small and that way if someone else doesn't have Web Essentials installed they can still get the site to work locally

Answer (score 0):

If using DotLess with something like WebGrease and System.Web.Optimization to bundle, check out the LessTransform code here:

https://github.com/philipproplesch/Web.Optimization/blob/master/src/Web.Optimization.Bundles.Less/LessTransform.cs

You need to do some funky stuff to get the import command to work when compiling and bundling.  There's also a `LessBundle` definition in the project, but when I made my port I just declared a standard `Bundle` and applied the transform to it.

Excerpted here, as of 10/15/2014:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using Web.Optimization.Common;
using dotless.Core.configuration;

namespace Web.Optimization.Bundles.Less
{
    public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
    {
        private readonly DotlessConfiguration _configuration;

        public LessTransform(DotlessConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public LessTransform()
            : this(DotlessConfiguration.GetDefaultWeb())
        { }

        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var file in response.Files)
            {
                var path =
                   context.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(
                       file.IncludedVirtualPath);

                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);

                if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var content = ResolveImports(fileInfo);

                builder.AppendLine(
                    _configuration.Web
                        ? dotless.Core.LessWeb.Parse(content, _configuration)
                        : dotless.Core.Less.Parse(content, _configuration));
            }

            response.ContentType = ContentType.Css;
            response.Content = builder.ToString();
        }

        private static readonly Regex s_lessImportRegex =
            new Regex("@import [\"|'](.+)[\"|'];", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        private static string ResolveImports(FileInfo file)
        {
            var content = File.ReadAllText(file.FullName, Encoding.UTF8);

            return s_lessImportRegex.Replace(
                content,
                match =>
                {
                    var import = match.Groups[1].Value;

                    // Is absolute path?
                    Uri uri;
                    if (Uri.TryCreate(import, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                    {
                        return match.Value;
                    }

                    var path =
                        Path.Combine(
                            file.Directory.FullName,
                            import);

                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(
                            string.Concat("Unable to resolve import ", import));
                    }

                    return match.Value.Replace(import, path);
                });
        }
    }
}
```